# Show data from Prismic.io in GatsbyJS frontend

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I was playing around with prismic.io as a content source for a gatsby site and just can't figure out why I can't output certain data.

The graphql tool from gatsby returns all the right data so the query itself seems fine:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
query PageQuery {
    allPrismicDocument {
      edges {
        node {
          data{
             product_image {
              url
            }
            product_name {
              text
            }
            product_price
            product_description {
              text
            }
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }
`
```

Now inside the page, when adding values such as:

```
{node.data.product_price}
{node.data.product_image.url}
```

it works just fine and outputs the correct data. However when I try:

```
{node.data.product_name.text}
or
{node.data.product_name}
```

I get nothing at all. Searched everywhere but there aren't many resources for using these two tools together yet:/

Any pointers would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `product_name` field is a Prismic Rich Text or Title field. If that's the case, then the field is an array of text blocks. You have two options for this:

1. Use the `prismic-react` development kit to help you display the field. Here is the [Prismic documentation for this](https://prismic.io/docs/reactjs/rendering/rich-text). This shows you how to use the RichText.render() and RichText.asText() helper functions to display this field type on a React front-end (which should work for Gatsby as well). It would look something like this:

   `{RichText.asText(node.data.product_name)}`
2. If the field only has one block of text, you could just grab the first element of the array. Like this:

   `{node.data.product_name[0].text}`

Comment: Yes it worked thank you so much!! for now I just tried the 2nd way which works like a charm. Will fiddle around with your first suggestion over the weekend for sure:)